# the bump function is smooth

Tags: real-analysis

consider the function

\begin{align*}
f(x)=&\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
 e^{\frac{-1}{x}} \quad & x>0\\
 0 \quad & x\leq0.
 \end{array}
\right.
\end{align*}
I want to prove that the function $\beta(x)=e^2f(1-x)f(x+1)$ is smooth. And also I want to show that for $|x|<1 : \beta(x)=e^{\frac{-2x^2}{x^2-1}}$

I don't know it can help or not but I could prove that $f$ is smooth by induction and L'Hopital but I can't prove the claims about $\beta(x)$.

Anybody can prove it?

Comment: $\beta$ is smooth as it is a product of two smooth functions.

Comment: And on $|x|<1$, $\beta = e^2 e^{-\frac{1}{1-x}} \ \ \ \ e^{-\frac{1}{1+x}}\ \ \ =$....

Comment: @John Thank you so much :)